# Extracting multiple rows for each ID based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, summarize

I have a data frame with thousands of rows but a sample is given below:

```
     userid     event
1     123        view
2     123        view
3     123       order
4     345        view
5     345        view
6     345        view
7     345       order
8     111        view
9     111       order
10    111        view
11    111        view
12    111        view
13    333        view
14    333        view
15    333        view
```

dput(data)

```
structure(list(userid = c(123, 123, 123, 345, 345, 345, 345, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 333, 333, 333), eventaction = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("order", 
"view"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("userid", "event"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I am looking at doing is to extract all the rows of userid's that contains the word "order" under event. The result will contain all the rows for userid's excluding userid = 333 as the eventaction does not contain an order entry.

The second task is to count the number of occurences for "view" before the order entry. I will appreciate help and pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there only one `"order"` per `userid`?

Comment: It could be multiple entries of "order". The idea is to extract users who ordered and then count the number of views before an order was placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'userid', `if` there are `any` 'event' that is an 'order' in the 'userid', return the Subset of Data.table' (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,if(any(event=="order")) .SD , by = userid]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we `filter` for `any` 'order' in the 'event' after grouping by 'userid'.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(userid) %>%
    filter(any(event == "order"))
```

Comment: what if we have to check for two conditions instead of one. e.g., if we need to check if there was a view as well as an order entry by customer id. can you suggest what edits will be required in the above code?

Comment: @syebill In that case `setDT(data)[, if(any(event == "order") & any(event=="view")) .SD, by = userid]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. you are amazing and a great data wrangler!

Answer (score 1):

To do your second task with the possibility that there are more than one order for a `userid`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(userid) %>% 
       mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>% 
       filter(event=="order") %>% 
       mutate(num_views_before=c(first(row_num),diff(row_num))-1)
```

Notes:

1. We `group_by` `userid`.
2. We add a column to track the rows for the group.
3. We keep only those rows with "order".
4. We compute the number of views before each order using `diff` on the row numbers created beforehand.

To test, I modified your data to change the event in row 12 to "order" so that `userid=111` has two orders.

Modified data:

```
structure(list(userid = c(123, 123, 123, 345, 345, 345, 345, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 333, 333, 333), event = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("order", 
"view"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("userid", "event"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
##   userid event
##1     123  view
##2     123  view
##3     123 order
##4     345  view
##5     345  view
##6     345  view
##7     345 order
##8     111  view
##9     111 order
##10    111  view
##11    111  view
##12    111 order
##13    333  view
##14    333  view
##15    333  view
```

With this data, we get:

```
##Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
##Groups: userid [3]
##
##  userid  event row_num num_views_before
##   <dbl> <fctr>   <int>            <dbl>
##1    123  order       3                2
##2    345  order       4                3
##3    111  order       2                1
##4    111  order       5                2
```

Answer (score 0):

With *standard* R, if you call `mydat` to your data.frame:

```
myusers <- mydat[mydat$event == "order", "userid"]
mydat[mydat$userid %in% myusers,]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
df[df$userid %in% df[df$event=="order",]$userid,]
```

OR with `subset`:

```
subset(df, df$userid %in% subset(df, event=="order")$userid)
```

OR `match` function:

```
subset(df, match(df$userid, subset(df, event=="order")$userid, nomatch = 0)>0)
```

OR using `sqldf` library:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df where df.userid in (select df.userid from df where df.event=='order')")

   # userid event
# 1     123  view
# 2     123  view
# 3     123 order
# 4     345  view
# 5     345  view
# 6     345  view
# 7     345 order
# 8     111  view
# 9     111 order
# 10    111  view
# 11    111  view
# 12    111  view
```